# Need help in proving $\lambda \notin \sigma(M_f) \implies \lambda \notin \text {ess ran} f.$

Tags: measure-theory, spectral-theory

> Let $(X,\mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $f \in L^{\infty} (\mu).$ Let $M_f$ denote the multiplication operator on $L^2(\mu).$ Then show that $\lambda \notin \sigma (M_f) \implies \lambda \notin \text {ess ran} f.$

If $(M_f - \lambda)$ is invertible then it is bounded below i.e. there exists $\alpha \gt 0$ such that $\|(M_f - \lambda)h\|_2 \geq \alpha \|h\|_2,$ for all $h \in L^2(\mu).$ Does it anyway imply that $\lambda \notin \text {ess ran} f\ $? Could anybody give me some hint to proceed?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Suppose, toward a contradiction, that $\lambda$ is in the essential range of $f$. So you have a set $E$, of positive measure, on which the values of $f$ are very close to $\lambda$. Let $h$ be the characteristic function of $E$ and see what your inequality about norms says.

Comment: @Andreas Blass I have tried to approach from a different angle. Let $\lambda \notin \sigma (M_f).$ Then $(M_f - \lambda)$ would be invertible. So there exists $T \in \mathscr B (L^2(\mu))$ such that $(M_f - \lambda) T = \text {Id}.$ So for any $h \in L^2(\mu)$ we have $(f-\lambda) T(h) = h.$ Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure. Then we claim that $f \neq \lambda$ a.e. Let $A = \{x \in X\ |\ f(x) = \lambda \}.$ If $\mu (A) \gt 0$ then for any $h \in L^2(\mu),$ $h = 0$ $\mu$ a.e. on $A.$

Comment: Now by $\sigma$-finiteness of $\mu$ we can find some $B \subseteq A$ such that $0 \lt \mu (B) \lt \infty.$ Now define a function $h : X \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $$h(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in B \\ 0 & \text {otherwise} \end{cases}$$ Then clearly $h \in L^2(\mu)$ and it violates the condition mentioned in the above comment. This shows that $f \neq \lambda$ $\mu$ a.e. Then it is easy to see that $(M_f - \lambda) = M_g,$ where $g$ is defined by $$g(x) = \begin{cases} (f - \lambda)^{-1} (x) & x \in A^c \\ 0 & \text {otherwise} \end {cases}$$

Comment: Now since $(M_f - \lambda)$ is bounded it follows that $M_g$ is bounded and hence $g \in L^{\infty} (\mu).$ So there exists $B \gt 0$ such that $(f - \lambda)^{-1} (x) \leq B$ $\mu$ a.e. on $B.$ This in turn shows that $(f - \lambda) \geq \varepsilon,$ $\mu$ a.e. where $\varepsilon = B^{-1}.$ This shows that $\mu \left ( \left \{x \in X\ |\ |f(x) - \lambda| \leq \varepsilon \right \} \right ) = 0.$ This shows that $\lambda \notin \text {ess ran} f.$ But I don't know how to proceed if the underlying measure is not $\sigma$-finite. Can you please verify my argument @Andreas Blass?

Comment: Sorry in the second comment I mean $(M_f - \lambda)^{-1} = M_g$ and $(M_f - \lambda)^{-1}$ is bounded by *Bounded Inverse Theorem.* So according to my first comment $T = M_g$ and it is bounded and hence $g \in L^{\infty} (\mu).$ After that everything is fine, I guess. Please verify it @Andreas Blass.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: (This assumes some functional analysis)

Let $B:=\mathscr{B}(L^2(\mu))$ be the set of bounded linear operators on $L^2(\mu)$. This is a unital $C^*$-algebra, and $A:=L^\infty(\mu)$ is a unital $C^*$-subalgebra of $B$ (more precisely, the map $f\mapsto M_f$ is an isometric embedding and $M_1=1_B$). It follows (see 11.29 in Rudin's *Functional Analysis*, page 296 of the second edition)) that
$$
\sigma_A(f)=\sigma_B(M_f)
$$
(in fact, $x$ is invertible in $A$ iff it is invertible in $B$).

All this tells you that you can just work with invertibility in $L^\infty(f)$, which is simpler to deal with.